# Creating specific permisions for DB user

Tags: permissions, sql-server-2019, service-broker

I need to give access to CREATE QUEUE and DROP QUEUE queries. Can`t find that information over the internet, only found that db_ddladmin or db_owner fixed database roles, or the sysadmin have that role, but in my case, these roles are too high.

Please guide me, how to do it.

Thanks,
Val

Comment: Add more information to your question about the specific use case for the need to create queues. Is this for SqlDependency or QueryNotifications? `ALTER` permissions on the object's schema are required to create objects in that schema which will confer permissions to drop other objects in that schema, and in the case of service broker, you likely will need additional permissions such as `CREATE SERVICE`.

Answer (score 0):

is something like this new custom role what you are looking for?

```
CREATE ROLE [db_queue_admin] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO
GRANT CREATE QUEUE TO db_queue_admin;
GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA :: your_queue_schema_name TO db_queue_admin;
```